# what's the difference between "npm install" and "npm --userconfig=./.npmrccorp i "

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to know what the difference is between these two commands in nodejs
`npm install`     and,
`npm --userconfig=./.npmrccorp i`

As far as I know, both will install the required node modules specified in the `package.json`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are different

- `npm install`: This is the install modules mentioned in `package.json` while considering the configuration file from your home directory i.e. `~/.npmrc` . This is same as `npm i`
- `npm --userconfig=./.npmrccorp i`: This will install the modules as mentioned in `package.json`while considering the configuration file supplied by the `--userconfig` argument. The last `i` and `install` are interchangeable. This can be rewritten as `npm --userconfig=./.npmrccorp install` also

Answer (score 1):

One uses npm with the regular default settings, the other uses npm with the settings defined in the file `./.npmrccorp`.

An example common use case for this is if you work at a company that has its own npm registry.

The settings in `./.npmrccorp` will fetch npm modules from your company's private npm registry, but the default settings would fetch modules from the default one at `registry.npmjs.org`.